# Footnotes on touch device with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, ionic3

I would like to have my Angular app be able to display a footnote with a click event on mobile devices ***for text injected with nativeElement.innerHTML***. I don't think that I did a very good job of explaining it in the first try so I will try again.I actually have read about Templating and Data Binding. The problem is that it does not work when the text is injected with nativeElement.innerHTML so I need some other way of doing this. Here is some code and a plunkr which fails.

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="toggleFootNotes()">toggle</button>

      <p>Text in template:  
          And when
            <sup>a
              <span *ngIf=this.showFootnotes> testing 1 2 3 </span>
            </sup> 
          he came ...  
      </p>

      <div #textwithfootnote></div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('textwithfootnote') textwithfootnote: ElementRef;
  name:string;
  public showFootnotes: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  public toggleFootNotes() {
      this.showFootnotes = !this.showFootnotes;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.textwithfootnote.nativeElement.innerHTML = " \
    \n<p>Text injected: \
    \n    And when \
    \n        <sup>a \
    \n          <span *ngIf=this.showFootnotes> testing 1 2 3 </span> \
    \n        </sup> \
    \n      he came ...  \
    \n  </p>";
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wY2vRt4dcMHq12SlJSmv

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In angular you bind event listeners either with `()`-syntax in the template or via `HostBinding` decorator. And to bind some HTML you bind it via the `innerHTML` attribute directive. But you could also use a simple `ng-template` to show and hide your foot notes. `*` as a directive prefix is just syntactic sugar, it automatically wraps the element in a `ng-template`.

Inside your components template:

```
<button (click)="toggleFootNotes()">toggle</button>
...
<p *ngIf="showFootNotes">
    My footnotes.
</p>
```

and inside your component:

```
public showFootNotes: boolean = false;

...

public toggleFootNotes() {
    this.showFootnotes = !this.showFootNotes;
}
```

You sould definitly read the docs about [Template & Data binding](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data).

> **DON'T** interact with the DOM outside of angular unless you know what you're doing and really need to do it.

*So you should get rid of jQuery, you won't need it.*

Comment: Okay, but the page may have a couple of dozen footnotes and I just want to display the one they click on. Can you put a button inside of html which is injected with .innerHTML??